# refactoring multiple source codes

Tags: editing

How do I add a new line at the beginning of every file I have in a directory? How do I eliminate useless spaces and tabs at the end of each line of each file in my directory?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic script that I have put together. Replace the DIR constant with the path to the directory which contains the files.

```
import os

DIR = "" # Change to the directory which contains the files

for srcfile in os.listdir(DIR):
    original = os.path.join(DIR, srcfile)
    temp = os.path.join(DIR, "%s_tmp" % srcfile)
    with open(original) as infile:
        with open(temp, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write("\n")
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write("%s\n" % line.rstrip())

    os.remove(original)
    os.rename(temp, original)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple variation using a bash script that inserts an empty line at the beginning of every file in a directory passed as an argument that must exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
# requires one argument that is path to a directory whose files you want
# to add an initial line to

for f in $(ls $1)
do
    mv $1/$f $1/$f.orig
    echo -e "\t" > $1/$f
    cat $1/$f.orig >> $1/$f
    rm $1/$f.orig
done
```